# bash unique line id

Tags: text-processing, sort, uniq

Input: file with sorted lines

Output: file with (first or any) unique line ids from the input file

Example

Input

```
abbylove
abbylove
abbylove
abbylover
abbylover
abbylovesyou
abbylovesyou
abbylsmith
abbylsmith
abbylyn
abbylynn
```

Output

```
1
4
6
8
10
11
```

0-indexed also OK.

How to create such an output? I don't find such an option in shell `uniq` and `sort` commands.

Updated.

I'm trying to find unique adjacent lines from a file that differs only in years, that they contain. For example, I'd like to filter the file

```
abbylove2016
abbylove2017
abbylove2018
abb1999ylover
abb2005ylover
abbyloves2001you
abbyloves2006you
abbylsm1980ith
abbylsm2010ith
abbylyn2002
abbylynn1999
```

and get only

```
abbylove2016
abb1999ylover
abbyloves2001you
abbylsm1980ith
abbylyn2002
abbylynn1999
```

I thought removing years could help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with GNU `uniq`

```
$ nl input | uniq --skip-fields=1 | cut -f1
     1
     4
     6
     8
    10
    11
```

Comment: Does not cope with the data in the updated part of the question though.  For that, use the line numbers found by `uniq` to fetch those lines in the original file (the one from the updated question).  This requires a temporary file though, or a process substitution in `bash`. I'm assuming this is what the user will attempt next.

Comment: @Kusalananda I added a second answer for that (IMHO barely related) part

Comment: Ah, yes, that would skip non-consecutive equal lines as well. For example, if the last line was the same as the first, then it would not get printed.

Comment: OK I'm just going to delete the whole thing

Comment: No, no need for that. Just say what it does and why. It may well be correct enough for the user. And they already accepted your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of what the previous line was, and outputting the wanted info when the current line is not equal to the previous:

```
$ awk '$0 != prev { print NR, $0; prev = $0 }' file
1 abbylove
4 abbylover
6 abbylovesyou
8 abbylsmith
10 abbylyn
11 abbylynn
```

or

```
$ awk '$0 != prev { print NR; prev = $0 }' file
1
4
6
8
10
11
```

---

For the updated question:

```
$ awk '{ curr=$0; gsub("[0-9]","",curr) } curr != prev { print; prev = curr }' file
abbylove2016
abb1999ylover
abbyloves2001you
abbylsm1980ith
abbylyn2002
abbylynn1999
```

This works by first removing all digits from the current line, and then comparing the result of that to the previous line (with digits removed).  If there's a mismatch, the original current line is printed.

Comment: Your solution for the updated question didn't filter out any unnecessary lines like it should. All lines remain.

Comment: @dizcza I've tested this with three different `awk` implementations on the data that you posted, and I'm getting the expected output. Could you please show exactly what command you used?

Comment: @Kusalananda `awk '{ curr=$0; gsub("[[:digit:]]","",curr) } curr != prev { print; prev = curr }' test`, where `test` file contains the input lines.

Comment: @dizcza If the input in `test` is identical to what you show in the question, then I get the six lines of output that you require. Is the input file an ordinary Unix text file? What system are you running this on?

Comment: @dizcza Could you try with `[0-9]` in place of `[[:digit:]]`? We found, [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45674239#45674239), that this may be an issue in some verisons of `awk`, possibly relating to your locale settings.

Comment: Yes, [0-9] works.

Comment: @dizcza Ah, good. Then may I ask what locale you use? What does `locale` output? Just for my own curiosity.

Comment: ```LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: @dizcza Ok. Odd, but ok. I'll take greater care with that sort of regular expressions in answers in the future then I guess.